# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application while importing win32com

Tags: python, win32com

I tried this email sending [sample code](https://topbullets.com/2016/09/21/auto-send-email-through-outlook-via-python-code-topbullets-com/#comment-10670):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Sep 21 15:36:00 2016

@author: Deepesh.Singh
"""

import win32com.client as win32
import psutil
import os
import subprocess

# Drafting and sending email notification to senders. You can add other senders' email in the list
def send_notification():
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'abc@xzs.com; bhm@ert.com', 
    mail.Subject = 'Sent through Python'
    mail.body = 'This email alert is auto generated. Please do not respond.'
    mail.send

# Open Outlook.exe. Path may vary according to system config
# Please check the path to .exe file and update below

def open_outlook():
    try:
        subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Outlook.exe'])
        os.system("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Outlook.exe");
    except:
        print("Outlook didn't open successfully")

# Checking if outlook is already opened. If not, open Outlook.exe and send email
for item in psutil.pids():
    p = psutil.Process(item)
    if p.name() == "OUTLOOK.EXE":
        flag = 1
        break
    else:
        flag = 0

if (flag == 1):
    send_notification()
else:
    open_outlook()
    send_notification()
```

but keep hitting the following error when I run the code on command prompt:

```
C:\<>\Desktop\Exp>python sendemail.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sendemail.py", line 40, in <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Can someone please guide me on how to fix this error? Or is their a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: please tell your python version and bit? and OS ?

Comment: Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. 
I am using Windows 10 64 bit OS

Comment: I re-installed pywin32 (32-bit version) as pointed out by Trapli below and also installed psutil module and restarted my system. Issue is resolved now and I am able to send email. Thank you all for helping me out.

Comment: More details: [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546).

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a x86 vs x64 issue. If you use 64 bit python, import a 64 bit dll, if you use 32 bit python, import the 32 bit dll.

Edit2:
I think [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20221/) is what you are looking for. See [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) for details.

Comment: Your answer is pretty self-explanatory, a more formal and better answer should address the question *”how you can do that?”*, instead of just saying “you need to do this”, but without telling them how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Win32
Extensions for Python? Make
sure you pick the correct
installer for your system and
version of Python otherwise it
may not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed pywin32 (32-bit version) as pointed out by Trapli and also installed psutil module and restarted my system. Issue is resolved now and I am able to send email.
Thank you all for helping me out.